# How to detect and remove the images containing multiple sub-images in a dataset?

Tags: python, dataset

I have a human dataset that contains some images like following format (an image is consist of multiple sub-images):

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmHWq.jpg)
[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS0QF.png)

How can I detect this kind of images from my dataset using Python?

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of "this kind" with more details.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use cv2 to check analyse your pictures.

Picture1 would be pretty easy to recognize. Just check if there is one or multiple vertical stripes containing pure white.

The second picture is ab bit more difficult to recognize. maybe check with a recursive function if the lower half of the picture ist contained within the upper half?

Here are some resources:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html
https://learnopencv.com/read-display-and-write-an-image-using-opencv

Greetings Fischi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).